# Azure Storage Account requests getting throttled despite not reaching limits

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-powershell, azure-rm

I'm running into the below exception intermittently when running the Set-AzureRmStorageAccount cmdlet:

```
Set-AzureRmStorageAccount : The request is being throttled.
At D:\StorageAccount.psm1:36 char:4
+             Set-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $Resource.Re ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmStorageAccount], CloudExce 
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.SetAzureSt 
   orageAccountCommand
```

The cmdlet that I'm running is

```
Set-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "RG" -Name "SA" -EnableHttpsTrafficOnly $true
```

So in order to repro this issue, I put the above cmdlet in a while loop and executed it.

However, I immediately started seeing the throttling error again and when I checked the portal for total transactions, it is not even close to the limits specified in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits):

```
    The following limits apply when performing management operations using the Azure Resource Manager only.
    
    Resource                                     Default Limit   
Storage account management operations (read)    800 per 5 minutes    
Storage account management operations (write)   200 per hour     
Storage account management operations (list)    100 per 5 minutes
```

The screenshot from the azure portal shows only around 75 requests as shown below

[image: Screenshot of requests to storage account from azure portal]

Can someone help me understand why I'm seeing this throttling error so soon and if there is a way to see the source of requests to the storage account?

Thanks!

Comment: What are those displayed metrics showing, specifically? Is it showing management API calls, or calls to your storage account in general? It's the management api's that have the throttling limits. Storage content manipulation itself (e.g. manipulating blobs/queues/tables) is a different API.